# Show hidden ribbon elements

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, microsoft-dynamics

In previous iterations, there were some ribbon buttons and tabs that were hidden via the HideCustomAction in the customizations.xml.  Now the client is requesting that some of those elements be shown. I've exported the solution, and removed the hide custom action. The tab is still not shown even though the HideCustomAction was removed. Are there any additional steps needed to be taken to re-show the hidden elements?

Comment: Note: This CRM instance has the original Hide Custom Action in a managed solution that I do not have access to its' customizations.xml. I removed the hide action in a seperate solution with the affected entity included and reimported with no success

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best thing would be to have the developer of the managed solution update the solution with the proper ribbon configuration.  That's the supported approach.

If that isn't an option, you could look to recreate the CustomAction buttons in a solution with different IDs but the same actions.  Basically creating two sets of the buttons.